# Creating and loading a toolbar in dialog app and the Scale setting on Windows

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, toolbar

My dialog application loads a 32 bit PNG toolbar like this:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateToolbar()
{
    constexpr DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;

    CMFCToolBar::m_dblLargeImageRatio = 1; // AJT v20.1.7 Bug fix
    if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
        dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
    {
        dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
        m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);

        CMFCToolBarInfo info;

        info.m_uiColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;

        m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, info, FALSE);

        const CSize sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
        m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
            SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        // Move all controls down
        const CPoint ptOffset(0, sizeToolBar.cy);

        CRect  rcChild;
        CWnd* pwndChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
        while (pwndChild)
        {
            if (pwndChild->GetSafeHwnd() != m_ToolBar.GetSafeHwnd())
            {
                pwndChild->GetWindowRect(rcChild);
                ScreenToClient(rcChild);
                rcChild.OffsetRect(ptOffset);
                pwndChild->MoveWindow(rcChild, FALSE);
            }
            pwndChild = pwndChild->GetNextWindow();
        }

        // Resize the window
        CRect rcWindow;
        GetWindowRect(rcWindow);
        rcWindow.bottom += sizeToolBar.cy;
        MoveWindow(rcWindow, FALSE);

    }
}
```

This function is called from `OnInitDialog`. When you change your display settings on Windows (11 in my case) to have a Scale setting of 100% it looks right:

[image]

But I tried it on a Windows 11 laptop whose preferred display settings is 125% Scale and it looks like this:

[image]

The toolbar is cropped. The `m_Toolbar` is of type `CMFCToolBar`.

How do I ensure that my dialog doesn't crop the toolbar?

---

I don't know if this is connected but I realised my dialog is derived from my own class `CResizingDialog`, which in turn is derived from `CDialogEx`. Now, my class does have:

```
void CResizingDialog::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI)
{
    // Set the minimum window size to initial size.
    if (!m_rcInit.IsRectEmpty()) {
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_rcInit.Width();
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();

        if (m_bLimitToHorizontalResizing)
            lpMMI->ptMaxTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();
    }

    __super::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}
```

Note, I am stripping out the code for saving the window position for brevity. But I can show it if you think it necessary.

```
BOOL CResizingDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();

    // Save Initial window size to m_rcInit
    GetWindowRect(&m_rcInit);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

I note in the comments that some questioned to sizing for 125%. Well, it is either the system or my code affecting things.

Since my main window does save / restore its position I will include that code afterall:

```
void CResizingDialog::RestoreWindowPosition(CString strWindow, CWnd* pWindow, bool bOverrideState)
{
    int     max_x{}, max_y{};
    RECT    rtWindow{};

    if (pWindow == nullptr)
        return;

    // Only restore if there is a previously saved position
    rtWindow.top = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Top"), -1);
    rtWindow.left = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Left"), -1);
    rtWindow.bottom = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Bottom"), -1);
    rtWindow.right = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Right"), -1);
    if (rtWindow.top != -1 && rtWindow.left != -1 &&
        rtWindow.bottom != -1 && rtWindow.right -1)
    {
        max_x = rtWindow.right - rtWindow.left;
        max_y = rtWindow.bottom - rtWindow.top;

        // Get a handle to the monitor
        HMONITOR hMonitor = ::MonitorFromPoint(
            CPoint(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        // Get the monitor info
        MONITORINFO monInfo{};

        monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
        if (::GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monInfo) == 0)
            AfxMessageBox(_T("GetMonitorInfo failed"));
        else
        {
            // Adjust for work area
            rtWindow.left += monInfo.rcWork.left - monInfo.rcMonitor.left;
            rtWindow.top += monInfo.rcWork.top - monInfo.rcMonitor.top;

            // Ensure top left point is on screen
            const CRect rcMonWork(monInfo.rcWork);
            const CRect rtRestored(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top, rtWindow.right, rtWindow.bottom);

            // Deflate the rectangle so we have a margin
            if (rcMonWork.PtInRect(rtRestored.TopLeft()) == FALSE ||
                rcMonWork.PtInRect(rtRestored.BottomRight()) == FALSE)
            {
                rtWindow.left = monInfo.rcWork.left;
                rtWindow.top = monInfo.rcWork.top;
            }

            if (m_bOnlyStorePosition)
            {
                // We must override the dimensions of the dialog. This is because the user
                // might have text scale in effect.
                CRect rtOrg;
                GetWindowRect(&rtOrg);
                // But we want to show it in the previous place (albeit slightly off position)
                pWindow->MoveWindow(rtWindow.left, rtWindow.top, rtOrg.Width(), rtOrg.Height());
            }
            else
            {
                rtWindow.right = rtWindow.left + max_x;
                rtWindow.bottom = rtWindow.top + max_y;

                // Restore window size
                pWindow->MoveWindow(&rtWindow, FALSE);
            }
        }

        if (bOverrideState)
        {
            // Let us override by restoring the window state
            const int iState = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(strWindow, _T("ShowCmd"), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            pWindow->ShowWindow(iState);
        }
    }
}

void CResizingDialog::SaveWindowPosition(CString strWindow, const CWnd* pWindow)
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT wp{};

    if (pWindow == nullptr)
        return;

    pWindow->GetWindowPlacement(&wp);

    // Commit to registry
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Top"), wp.rcNormalPosition.top);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Left"), wp.rcNormalPosition.left);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Bottom"), wp.rcNormalPosition.bottom);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("Right"), wp.rcNormalPosition.right);
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileInt(strWindow, _T("ShowCmd"), wp.showCmd);
}
```

There is not much more I can show you.

Comment: Size the dialog to fit the toolbar. To do so, set up a [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) handler in your dialog's message map. I don't know whether this is enough or if you have to install a [`WM_DPICHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged) handler as well.

Comment: @IInspectable Alright, but the dialog needs to be wider than the toolbar it seems so how do we know how much extra to add to the toolbar width?

Comment: The screenshots don't make sense to me. The cutoff seems less than the 25% you'd expect if this were a scaling issue. It's almost as if `CalcFixedLayout()` is ignoring (or not correctly scaling) the separators. Have you looked into its implementation to see what it's doing?

Comment: There's also the odd cutoff at the bottom of the calendar controls that shouldn't be there. Is this application manifested to be (per-monitor) [DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows), or is it relying on the system to supply the scaling?

Comment: @IInspectable At the moment it is relying on the system.

Comment: Well looking at your two screenshots, I'd say that the issue is not with your toolbar but with your window size, it's clearly not 125% larger. Running at 100% DPI your first windows is approx 553 pixels wide, so I'd expect when running at 125% DPI that your window should be approx 691 pixels wide, but it is not.

Comment: Might be worth checking OnGetMinMaxInfo, in case you've set a max size here, as this would explain why you're window is not the correct size.